# How to implement TCP connection pooling in java?

Tags: java, tcp, client-server, connection-pooling

Here, I managed to get a connection between a single server and single client but now my new hurdle is how to achieve a pool of TCP connections on client side in Java. I have gone through many sites, but at the end no fruitful solution was found. Here the class which I had used for obtaining connection to a server:

```java
public class TCPIPCommunicator {

    private final String MODULE="TCPIPCommunicator :";

    //private DeviceEntity deviceEntity;
    private static InetAddress inetServer = null;
    private static int devicePort = -1;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedOutputStream outputStream;
    private BufferedInputStream inputStream;
    private static boolean isLinkActive = false;
    private String IP="";
    
    public TCPIPCommunicator(String IP, int  devicePort) {
        this.IP=IP;
        this.devicePort=devicePort;
        initialize();
    }
    
    public static boolean isLinkActive(){
        return isLinkActive;
    }
    
    public static void setLinkStatus(boolean status){
        isLinkActive = status;
    }

    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println(MODULE+ "Inside initialize()" );
        setLinkStatus(false);
        try{
            inetServer = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        }catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "Error while creating inetaddress, Reason:"+uhe.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(MODULE+ "Connecting to - " +inetServer.getHostAddress() + ":" + devicePort);
        establishConnection();

            if(!isLinkActive()){
                //sendNotification(TCPIPConstants.LINK_DOWN);
                releaseResources();
                //resumeLinkSanityHelper();
            }
        System.out.println(MODULE+ "out of initialize(), isLinkActive :" + isLinkActive() );
    }

    public boolean establishConnection(){
        boolean isConnected = false;
        //Get the Connection to PMS Server.
        if(inetServer != null && devicePort > 0){
            try{
                clientSocket = new Socket(inetServer, devicePort);
                clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
            }catch(ConnectException ce){
                ce.printStackTrace();
                setLinkStatus(false);
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "Exception in initialize() " + "Couldnot Connect Server. Reason:"+ce.getMessage());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                setLinkStatus(false);           
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "Exception in initialize() " + "while creating socket ,Reason: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            //If got connection, Get the streams.
            if(clientSocket != null && !clientSocket.isClosed()){
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "in initialize(), Got Socket Connection." );
                try{
                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    outputStream=null;
                    setLinkStatus(false);
                    System.out.println(MODULE+ "Exception in initialize() while getting socket outputStream : " + e.getMessage());
                }

                if(outputStream != null){
                    try{
                        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        setLinkStatus(false);
                        System.out.println(MODULE+ "Exception in initialize() " + "while getting socket inputStream : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    setLinkStatus(true);
                }
                if(outputStream != null && inputStream != null){
                    isConnected = true;
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "in initialize(), Connection is closed or null." );
                setLinkStatus(false);
            }
        }
        return isConnected;
    }
    
    public int writeData(byte[] msg){
        int retValue = -1;
        try{
            if(isLinkActive() && (outputStream !=null)){
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "Writting data  ::::" + new String(msg)+ "::::");
                outputStream.write(msg);// ed
                outputStream.flush();
                retValue = 1;
            }else{
                System.out.println(MODULE+ " in writeData() link is down so status:" + retValue );
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            retValue = -1;
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "Exception in write() < message to be sent was = " + new String(msg) + " > : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(retValue == -1 && isLinkActive()){
            setLinkStatus(false);
            //sendNotification(TCPIPConstants.LINK_DOWN);
            //releaseResources();
            //resumeLinkSanityHelper();
        }
        System.out.println(MODULE+ " in writeData() Write status for ::"+ new String(msg) + ":: -->" +retValue);
        return retValue;
    }
    
    public String readData() {
        System.out.println(MODULE+"\tInside readDAta");
        String response = null;
        int bytesReceived=-1;
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        try{
            long timetoread = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(inputStream == null || !(isLinkActive())){
                System.out.println(MODULE+"Inputstream is null or link is down, returning null");
                return null;
            }
            
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting to read data");
                bytesReceived = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                System.out.println(MODULE+"# Byte Receieved #" + bytesReceived);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(MODULE+"Error in readData() , Reason:"+e.getMessage());
                if(isLinkActive()){
                    setLinkStatus(false);
                    //sendNotification(TCPIPConstants.LINK_DOWN);
                    releaseResources();
                    //resumeLinkSanityHelper();
                }
            }
            if(bytesReceived > 0){          
                response = new String(readBuffer,0,bytesReceived); // ed
                timetoread = System.currentTimeMillis() - timetoread;
                System.out.println(MODULE + "Total Bytes Received: " + bytesReceived);
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "Total Time Taken : " + timetoread);
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "Length of data received : " + response.length());
                System.out.println(MODULE+ "Data Received : ####" + response + "####");
            }else{
                ////////// HERE MEANS TCP CONNECTION STATUS WILL CLOSE_WAIT
                ////////// SO RELEASING CONNECTION.
                System.out.println(MODULE+ " Releasing Resource. bytesReceived is <= 0 : Total Bytes Received :"+ bytesReceived );
                if(isLinkActive()){
                    setLinkStatus(false);
                    //sendNotification(TCPIPConstants.LINK_DOWN);
                    releaseResources();
                    //resumeLinkSanityHelper();
                }
                System.out.println(MODULE+ " Resource has been released.");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "In catch : Data Received : ####" + response + "####");
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "Exception in readdata() : " + e);
        }finally{
            readBuffer=null;
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    public void releaseResources(){
        System.out.println(MODULE+ "Releasing Resources....");
        try{
            if(clientSocket !=null)
                clientSocket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "In releaseResources() :Error closing socket."+e.getMessage());
        }
        try{
            if(inputStream !=null )
                inputStream.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "In releaseResources() :Error closing inputStream."+e.getMessage());         
        }
        
        try{
            if(outputStream != null){
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(MODULE+ "in releaseResources() :Error closing outputStream.");
        }
        System.out.println(MODULE + "Resources Relased...");        
    }
}
```

Here `establishConnection()` method will be establish the connection to the server.

**Note**: I was thinking on using `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but as the requirement is for synchronous, I dropped this idea of using it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you think you need a connection pool?

Comment: @ThomasStets suppose 5 request comes and predefined pool is their for tcp connection than a ideal tcp connection object should be used to send request to server

Answer (score -1):

You can create a  variable  `Set<Socket>` to store all the client `Sockets` you created. Every time you  connect to the  server socket you can put the client
socket into this set. This set works as the pool.

Comment: how this is said to be connection pooling?

Comment: the clientsocket you created is  alive ,and every time  you want to use it  you  can fetch it  from the set directly,this reduces the  time  of setting up  connection.

Comment: How you will get know which connection object is in use and how you will maintain the same object in `set`? please show some code if you have the idea !!

Comment: Remove it from the set when you need one, and put it back when you've finished with it. If you get an IOException when using it, close it and don't put it back.

Comment: You have it back to front. You need a collection for the *free* sockets, not for the active ones. Every time you need a socket you pull one from the free list, creating it if there isn't one, or obeying whatever limit policy you want, and when you're finished you put it back.

Answer (score -1):

The sample code is like below,I use a Map ,the key is "host-port" ,and the value is a LinkedList containing the sockets related to the same url.

```
public class SocketPool{
    Map<String,LinkedList<Socket>> sockets;

public boolean establishConnection(String inetServer , int devicePort){
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(inetServer, devicePort);
        String socketKey  = inetServer + "-" + devicePort;
        if(clientSocket.isConnected()&&sockets.containsKey(socketKey)){
            sockets.get(socketKey).add(clientSocket);
        }else if(clientSocket.isConnected()&&!sockets.containsKey(socketKey)){
            LinkedList<Socket> socketSet = new LinkedList<Socket>();
            socketSet.add(clientSocket);
            sockets.put(socketKey, socketSet);
        }
        result = true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        result = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

public Socket fetchSocket(String inetServer , int devicePort){
    String socketKey  = inetServer + "-" + devicePort;
    Socket clientSocket =null;
    if(sockets.containsKey(socketKey)&&!sockets.get(socketKey).isEmpty()){
        clientSocket = sockets.get(socketKey).removeLast();
        int size = sockets.get(socketKey).size();
        if(size==0){
            sockets.remove(socketKey);
        }
    }
        return clientSocket;
}
//other functions
}
```

Comment: Not much point in testing `isConnected()` here. It doesn't magically become false, contrary to fairly widespread urban myth.

Comment: then, do you think  java api need this method? If the server is down,you dont check connection  status? If you dont think this is the right way,then show me your code. The method getInputStream in Socket check the connection  first.Could you tell me why?                           public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (isClosed())
            throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
        if (!isConnected())
            throw new SocketException("Socket is not connected");

Comment: `isConnected()` is there to tell you whether *you* have connected the socket, not whether it is still connected to the peer. There are very few correct uses of `isConnected()`, and this isn't one of them. Test it before you debate this further, and especially before you perpetrate any more guesswork. Your questions about `isClosed()` aren't relevant to my comments about `isConnected()`, but the answers seem perfectly obvious to me.